Ajax no dispara el evento success
Tengo una función con una petición Ajax que se dispara desde un formulario mediante el evento onkeyup del campo input que se valida. Esa petición Ajax se direcciona a la función de un controller que devuelve un json con la respuesta. Esta respuesta se renderiza en un formulario con los datos solicitados al controller.
La petición Ajax parece correcta, puesto que da un código 200 como respuesta, y si se pone la url directamente en el navegador llama a la función del controller sin problemas y devuelve la información correcta, pero aún así, ni dispara el evento success ni accede a la url pese a dar un OK200.
Este es el formulario:
<label for="">Código</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="codigo" name="codigo" onkeyup="buscarProducto(event, this, this.value)" placeholder="Escribe el código y enter" autofocus />

Esta la función con la petición Ajax:
<script>
function buscarProducto(e, tagCodigo, codigo) {
    var enterKey = 13;
    if (codigo != '') {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log(e);
        console.log(tagCodigo);
        console.log(codigo);
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?= base_url(); ?>productos/buscarPorCodigo/' + codigo,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(resultado) {
                if (resutado == 0) {
                    $(tagCodigo).val('');
                } else {
                    console.log(codigo);
                    $(tagCodigo).removeClass('has-error');
                    $("#resultado_error").html(resultado.error);
                    if (resultado.existe) {
                        $('#id_producto').val(resultado.datos.id);
                        $('#nombre').val(resultado.datos.nombre);
                        $('#cantidad').val(1);
                        $('#precio').val(resultado.datos.precio);
                        $('#subtotal').val(resultado.datos.precio);
                        $('#cantidad').focus();
                    } else {
                        $('#id_producto').val('');
                        $('#nombre').val('');
                        $('#cantidad').val('');
                        $('#precio').val('');
                        $('#subtotal').val('');
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                console.log('error');
            }
        });
    };
};

Esta es la función del controller:
public function buscarPorCodigo($codigo) 
{
    $session = session();
    $session->setFlashdata('mensaje', 'Buscando código');
    $this->productosModel
    ->select('*')
    ->where('codigo', $codigo)
    ->where('activo', 1);
    $datos = $this->productosModel->get()->getRow();
    $res['existe'] = false;
    $res['datos'] ='';
    $res['error'] = '';
    if ($datos) {
        $res['datos'] = $datos; 
        $res['existe'] = true;
    } else {
        $res['error'] = 'No existe el producto';
        $res['existe'] = false;
    }
    print_r($res);
    echo json_encode($res);
}

Esta es la ruta:
$routes->get('productos/buscarPorCodigo/(:any)',     'Productos::buscarPorCodigo/$1');

Esta es la respuesta del navegador desde la petición Ajax:

Y esta es la respuesta del controller poniendo la url directamente en el navegador:

Algo se me escapa y ya no sé qué revisar más. Se agradece la ayuda.

Creo que el metodo correcto es "done" y "fail" hace mucho lo deje de usar pero creo que success es la forma antigua

Se comporta igual. No llega a disparar el evento.

Lo único que he hecho en todo el código para que funcione ha sido quitar del controller print_r($res); Parece que afectaba a la respuesta.

Al hacer el print_r($res); estabas devolviendo dos veces el código: los datos en formato JSON, pero primero la variable PHP (como muestras en la captura). Esto hace que la respuesta no sea JSON válido. Como la llamada AJAX espera la respuesta en JSON y no lo es, vas a recibir una respuesta con código 200 (OK), pero la llamada AJAX va a fallar.

Cuando puedes, marca esta respuesta como aceptada para que la pregunta quede completa.
